# OmniFaces CDNResourceHandler could not find resources when not included locally

Tags: jsf, omnifaces

I'm using OmniFaces CDNResourceHandler to point my resources to a CDN, instead of local files.

I added this line in my XHTML file: `<h:outputStylesheet library="twitter-bootstrap" name="bootstrap.min.css" />`

And my faces-config.xml have this line:

```
<context-param>
    <param-name>org.omnifaces.CDN_RESOURCE_HANDLER_URLS</param-name>
    <param-value>
        twitter-bootstrap:bootstrap.min.css=https://somehost/twitter-bootstrap/3.3.7/bootstrap.min.css
    </param-value>
</context-param>
```

And I'm getting this error when access the page:

`Unable to find resource twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap.min.css`

Note: When I access the file at `https://somehost/twitter-bootstrap/bootstrap.min.css` I can download the file properly.

I'm using Mojarra under Wildfly configured to Development stage.

The resource handler is properly configured at `faces-config.xml` file.

```
<application>
    <resource-handler>org.omnifaces.resourcehandler.CDNResourceHandler</resource-handler>
</application>
```

I did some tests, and I notice that the error doesn't occurs if I create an empty file `bootstrap.min.css` under `WEBAPP_FOLDER/resources/twitter-bootstrap`. If I delete the file, the errors occurs again.

Even I use CDN, do I need to keep resources locally?

Comment: Hi @BalusC. Yes, the resource handler is properly configured. I updated the question with this information, and more information I discovery today. Thank you.

Comment: And my `faces-config.xml` have this line... I assume this should say `web.xml`. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `CDNResourceHandler` is primarily intented to move **auto-included** JSF resources to a CDN, such as `jsf.js` file from `<f:ajax>`, or `primefaces.js` and `jquery.js` from PrimeFaces, or to automatically switch to a CDN when installed in production.

You don't need it in your case with a permanent CDN resource. Just use plain `<link>`.

```
<link rel="stylesheet" src="https://somehost/twitter-bootstrap/bootstrap.min.css" />
```

This is also explicitly mentioned in [the `CDNResourceHandler` documentation](http://showcase.omnifaces.org/resourcehandlers/CDNResourceHandler).

> For non-JSF resources, you can just keep using plain HTML `<script>` and `<link>` elements referring the external URL

---

**Update**: as you're not the first one who wondered about this, I've as per [issue 122](https://github.com/omnifaces/omnifaces/issues/122) bypassed this technical restriction for OmniFaces 2.6. In other words, you do not necessarily need a local resource anymore.

Comment: Your answer is great, as always. But does not solve my problem because I can't use `<link>` tag in a JSF component. I have a lot of custom components using `@ResourceDependency`. I'll take a look your suggestion soon, to see how I can use in my case.

Comment: For now, your best bet is then creating an empty file at exactly the resource location in WAR.

Comment: @BalusC Solution from your comment doesn't work in OmniFaces 1.8.1. I know it is old but sadly in project we use this version.